# onLocationChanged data send from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

In my activity page have `onLocationChanged()` for get current location.

Also this activity have `ViewPager` and one of `viewpager` have fragment which show map. this map marker also changed by `onLocationChanged` lat long.

My question is how send activity `onLocationChanged()` data to map fragment page.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, please do some research

Comment: If you only want that in fragment, then let your fragment implement onLocationChanged

Answer (score 0):

U can create interface or save location on static `LatLng` and access in fragment

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways for communicating between `Activity` & `Fragment`. Here is simplest one.

get Fragment instance from `Activity`. Then set data by calling any method of `Fragment`.

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
```

Or

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
fragment.setLocation(passLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local broadcast.When you receive callback on activity in onLocationChanged().Then broadcast latlng and receive data in fragment.